# Unable to delete data from the cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just started integrating Flutter with Firebase, so I don't know if this is correct, but
When I try to delete a task in my app, it works fine, but when I look at it from the firestore database, the data is still there, so every time I reload the app, the data comes back, and I don't know what to do.

I wanted to delete the data from the local list and also in the firestore database.

Here is the code:

````
    try {
      if (user != null &&
          userTasksCollection != null &&
          toDoList.length > index) {
        final taskId = userTasksCollection!.doc(toDoList[index][0]);

        if (taskId.id.isNotEmpty) {
          // Delete the task from Firestore
          print('Task ID: ${taskId.id}');
          await taskId.delete();
          print('Deleted Task : ${toDoList[index][0]}');

          // Delete the task from Firestore.tasks collection
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('userTasksCollection')
              .doc(toDoList[index][0])
              .delete();

          // Delete the task from the tasks collection
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('tasks')
              .doc(toDoList[index][0])
              .delete();
          print('Deleting Task ID: ${toDoList[index][0]}');
        } else {
          print('Invalid document ID: ${toDoList[index][0]}');
        }
      }

      // Remove the task from the local list
      setState(() {
        toDoList.removeAt(index);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error deleting task from Firestore: $e');
    }   } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your doc-id matches the String of `toDoList[index][0]`.  You need to be using the doc-id in firestore.

You also might consider deleting from firestore first and your app last, or don't have any local references todo list and instead stream your todo's from firestore only, this eliminates that redundancy.

As for truly debugging what is going on for you: in your try catch, you can put `catch (e,s)`.  That allows you to print the error and the stack.  I assume you are getting the error from your try/catch, it's just not giving you helpful information.

look for an insufficient permission error as well, you might need to set your firebase rules differently.